# Pulling sql data into jquery autocomplete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've looked for an answer to this, but not finding exactly what I'm looking for. So, please excuse if this has been answered any another thread.

I have a very large sql table that I'd like to use in a jquery autocomplete input field. I know I need to return that data as json formatted, just not sure the best way to accomplish this. This field is in an ASP.net MVC application.

I know I could probably do a php page that returns the result, but that seems a bit messy to me. Is the best way to go is by creating a web service that I call?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code as to how I have accomplished this. I am using the [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) plugin

**The javascript on my View**

> $(function () {

```
        $("#suburb").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ManufacturerAutoComplete", "AutoComplete")', type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                    data: { searchText: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.DisplayValue, value: item.Suburb, id: item.SuburbID, postcode: item.Postcode, state: item.State }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {

                $("#state").val(ui.item.state);
                $("#postcode").val(ui.item.postcode);

            }
        });
```

**The input on my view**

```
<input type="text" id="suburb" />
```

**And finally the code from my Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult ManufacturerAutoComplete(string searchText)
        {
            
            if (searchText.Length > 2)
            {
                var service = new SuburbSearchServiceClient();
                var results = service.SearchSuburb(searchText, "Australia");

                List<Suburbs> sList = new List<Suburbs>();

                foreach (var item in results)
                {
                    sList.Add(new Suburbs() { SuburbID = item.SuburbID, Suburb = item.Suburb, State = item.State, Postcode = item.Postcode, DisplayValue = item.Suburb + " - " + item.State + " - " + item.Postcode });
                }

                return Json(sList);
            }
            else
            {
                var data = string.Empty;
                return Json(data);
            }
        }
```

You need to include the js and css from the jquery-ui plugin and the results of your auticomplete will be shown underneath the input element. As you can see from the JsonResult method, I am calling a web service to get my suburb data, but this could come from anywhere in reality.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I get this, but I'm still struggling with the sql commands needed. I'm still working on this so I'll update with my progress. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: I'm having an issue invoking the Json() method. What is the reference for that?